# Should we have "Migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com" when closing a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration, software-engineering-se

I apologize if that has been discussed before, didn't find anything when searching.  But I think it would be convenient if there was an option to vote to close/migrate questions to programmers.stackexchange.com.  (In fact, I believe that is in part why that site exists -- to get rid of those questions from SO)  Is this planned already?  Or is it too early because it's still in beta?

Comment: Nobody is going to set one up because they only do migration paths when a site is out of public beta, and thats not going to change any time soon. Why not leave comments?

Comment: I've been leaving some comments saying "this question would be better asked on programmers.stackexchange.com", myself.  I'd like a migration option when programmers.se gets out of beta.

Comment: It's out of beta now, this should be looked at again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It *should* happen - eventually.

But right now, the site is still in beta. Which means two thing:

1. It may well be killed off. In which case, questions migrated there would be lost. Not that that's necessarily a bad thing...
2. It isn't fully defined yet. So it wouldn't necessarily be clear *which* questions were appropriate for migration. The original definition of the site implied subjective-programming and programmer-related questions would be the focus, but [discussion is ongoing](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-can-we-avoid-programmers-se-from-becoming-the-se-black-sheep)

Comment: Most importantly than anything else is the fact that it's in beta -- there won't be migration until a site graduates

Comment: Thanks to all who chimed in.  Makes sense that this wouldn't happen 'til post-beta.

Comment: No longer in beta, this should be done now