# migrate high-vote, non-code questions to programmers?

Tags: discussion, migration, software-engineering-se

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we have “Migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com” when closing a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/should-we-have-migrate-to-programmers-stackexchange-com-when-closing-a-question)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384764/dealing-with-anti-microsoft-trolls-on-the-internet

Seems to me that this belongs on programmers, but it is already closed.

It has plenty of company, I bet.

Comment: Duplicate of [Should we have "Migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com" when closing a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/should-we-have-migrate-to-programmers-stackexchange-com-when-closing-a-question)

Comment: It's *already closed*