# Migrating subjective questions instead of closing them

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

I understand the reasoning for not wanting to have subjective questions on Stack Overflow (only what and how type questions for google ranking).
Personally, I think that there should be some mechanism to automatically move questions to a subdomain where subjective questions can be asked and discussed openly instead of closing them.

One of the repeated complains about the system is that it's too unkind to newbies, who might ask a question and have it closed very quickly. This would help to reduce that to some extent (although not entirely eliminate it, I'm sure).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we have "Migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com" when closing a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/should-we-have-migrate-to-programmers-stackexchange-com-when-closing-a-question)

Comment: @AdamDavis,   The suggestion was to move to site, where discussions are allowed, not to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ site.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Forking the discussion by allowing it to persist on both sites, especially when it's been determined that it doesn't belong on the original site, is counterproductive.  The person who asked the question now has to do twice the work in responding to answers, following up, etc.  The people who attempt to answer may be duplicating effort already done on the other site.</strike>

Perhaps if you showed some example questions that would benefit from this, we could discuss the problem more specifically.

Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.  There is a stackexchange site http://Programmers.Stackexchange.com which fields more subjective questions (though they still have to be constructive) and those with 3,000 or more reputation on stackoverflow already do have the option of moving appropriate questions from SO to that site, where they may receive a better response.

Comment: I am not suggesting that a copy remain on StackOverflow, but that the question, comments and answers all get moved.

Comment: why are questions getting closing when they could be getting migrated?

Comment: @k rey - In many cases there is no appropriate site for some questions to go to.  Stackoverflow isn't meant to answer, for instance, "Which is better, C or Java?" as it depends on the situation.  It also isn't suitable for "Should I buy PCLint?" because the answer may change in a year as open source programs mature, and the questions ans answers are meant to be (as much as possible) timeless and relevant years from now.  Still other questions are just chatty, "Hi, I'm new here, and I just wanted to introduce myself" doesn't fit - it's not a chat site or forum. So we need to close sometimes.

Comment: @AdamDavis, most of programming questions could expire relatively soon, because technology is evolving very quickly, so it should not be an argument to consider some questions as bad.

Answer (score -3):

UPDATE: there is a new site https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com to which SOFTWARE RECOMMENDATIONS questions should migrate.

It should be a separate subdomain, where discussions are allowed. Questions, that "do not fit in SO Q&A format" should be migrated to it.

See my suggestion https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180767/new-stackexchange-discussion-site-for-not-constructive-questions and similar [Discussion overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118284/discussion-overflow)

Comment: I hate that so many people downvoted your answer. Personally, I have found some of the most constructive questions out there are the ones that get closed - why else would they have 100's of up votes?  This is my biggest complaint about Stack Overflow is the closing nazis.  I've had multiple questions that were closed and other people commented they didn't understand why they were closed and disagreed with it.  This would alleviate some of this.  Plus, I think I would LOVE to browse a site with subjective programming questions.

Comment: There is also [Hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but both sites have insane [quality rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) so for a successful migration the question need to be really worthwhile ...