# Where is the "Migrate to Programmers.SE" option?

Tags: support, migration

[Should we have "Migrate to programmers.stackexchange.com" when closing a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/should-we-have-migrate-to-programmers-stackexchange-com-when-closing-a-questio) was tagged "status completed" by Jeff Atwood on 1/9/11, but I don't see any option under `Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic` to get it moved there.

Am I missing something, or is there not a current way to get non-code related questions to programmers.SE?

Comment: ...why was this downvoted?

Comment: random♦has just corrected the status. Programmers is a dangerous case because it mustn't be used as "stack overflows dumping ground" which it was initially

Comment: I see. So the proper course of action for a non-code related, but legitimate programming question is just to flag "other" and suggest migration to Programmers.SE to a mod, and let them decide?

Comment: @Pennstatephill yes but they should be of **extremely high quality**